Oracle ole db provider in visual studio 2022
Can we use Oracle OLE DB 32 bit or 64 bit driver with visual studio SSDT 2022?
We want to upgrade visual studio 2017 to visual studio 2022. So using of Oracle OLE DB 32 bit or 64 bit driver with visual studio SSDT 2022 will work?

You could just try it...
